# Delta Method In BigQuery or SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, google-app-engine, google-bigquery

So I am attempting to construct a delta curve that looks at how MLB players performance changes as they age.

> The “delta method” looks at all players who have played in back-to-back years. Many players have several back-to-back year “couplets,” obviously. For every player, it takes the difference between their rate of performance in Year I and Year II and puts that difference into a “bucket,” which is defined by the age of the player in those two years.

So lets say a player posted a batting average of .300 when he was 25 years old and then posted an average .310 when he was 26. So we take that +.10 difference and we put 25/26 age "bucket".

So I have a table constructed like this:

```
ID   Name      Age  Average
123  Joe Smith  25  .300
123  Joe Smith  26  .310
123  Joe Smith  27  .312
123  Joe Smith  28  .315
```

So the output I'm looking for is basically one where I'm creating a new row that identifies all instances where we see the difference in average if a player played back-to-back season (so if someone had an age 25 season but not an age 26 season, they wouldn't be included). I'm sure this involves some sort of CASE statement but I'm a little rusty on all this. If you don't know BigQuery, feel free to respond as you would if this was SQL.

Comment: The benefit of the answer that Mikhail posted is that it will result in a single table scan (and hence be half the cost).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In sql I would do a self-join on `id` and the age+1=age and calculate the difference:

```
select t1.id, t1.name, t1.age, t2.age, t1.average, t2.average, t2.average-t1.average as diff, concat(t1.age,'/',t2.age) as bucket
from yourtable t1
inner join yourtable t2
on t1.id=t2.id and t1.age+1=t2.age
```

The inner join will make sure that if there is no completed season for the next year, then the record is not included in the resultset.

Comment: Is there a way this can be accomplished without having to do a self-join? Like some form of a CASE statement or something?

Comment: You might be able to use an [analytic function](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#analytic-functions), e.g. `LAG`.

Comment: @ElliottBrossard mysql does not have a lag() function. It may be simulated through the use of session variables.

Comment: @RIPHarambe through the use of session variables probably yes, but then you would need a subquery to remove the records you do not need. A self join with indexes is lot more efficient than that.

Comment: @Shadow I was actually able to get your suggestion to work. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try below for BigQuery Standard SQL

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT ID, Name, Age, Average, bucket, ROUND(diff, 3) AS diff
FROM (
  SELECT *,
    CONCAT(CAST(Age AS STRING), '/', CAST(Age + 1 AS STRING)) AS bucket, 
    MAX(Average) OVER(nextYear) - Average AS diff
  FROM yourTable
  WINDOW nextYear AS (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Age RANGE BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND 1 FOLLOWING)
)
WHERE IFNULL(diff, 0) <> 0 
-- ORDER BY ID, Age
```

You can test/play with it using dummy data from your question

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH yourTable AS (
  SELECT 123 AS ID, 'Joe Smith' AS Name, 25 AS Age, .300 AS Average UNION ALL
  SELECT 123, 'Joe Smith', 26, .310 UNION ALL
  SELECT 123, 'Joe Smith', 27, .312 UNION ALL
  SELECT 123, 'Joe Smith', 28, .315 
)
SELECT ID, Name, Age, Average, bucket, ROUND(diff, 3) AS diff
FROM (
  SELECT *,
    CONCAT(CAST(Age AS STRING), '/', CAST(Age + 1 AS STRING)) AS bucket, 
    MAX(Average) OVER(nextYear) - Average AS diff
  FROM yourTable
  WINDOW nextYear AS (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Age RANGE BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND 1 FOLLOWING)
)
WHERE IFNULL(diff, 0) <> 0 
ORDER BY ID, Age
```